# intro book to learn trading desk basics like beta, gmv, Sharpe, etc

Tags: finance

Are there any recommendations regarding these basic topics one might find on a systematic trading desk? Also basic hedging theory and basis trading would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

the question is broad since beta, gmv, Sharpe apply to almost any finance position beyond trading. these topics are covered together in **Bodie, Kane, Marcus - Investments**. for hedging with derivatives see **Hull - Options, futures and other derivatives**